# Java Exception toString() inclusive causes

Tags: java, exception, tostring, throwable

Is there any good function collecting all causes of an Exception in a string?
The method `printStackTrace()` collect them with their StackTraces:

```
   HighLevelException: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
           at Junk.a(Junk.java:13)
           at Junk.main(Junk.java:4)
   Caused by: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
           at Junk.c(Junk.java:23)
           at Junk.b(Junk.java:17)
           at Junk.a(Junk.java:11)
           ... 1 more
   Caused by: LowLevelException
           at Junk.e(Junk.java:30)
           at Junk.d(Junk.java:27)
           at Junk.c(Junk.java:21)
           ... 3 more
```

But I just want the `getMessage()` of the causes:

```
   HighLevelException: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
   Caused by: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
   Caused by: LowLevelException
```

Should I write my own function?

Comment: Yes you should. If you want that in a log file though, depending on the log framework you may be able to use the correct template to log the exception as you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to write a simple method for that

```
static String message(Throwable e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(e.getMessage());
    Throwable t = e.getCause();
    while (t != null) {
        sb.append("\nCaused by: ").append(t.getMessage());
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I've added `sb.append(e.getMessage());` before the loop. I guess you're talking about it?

Comment: You're getting the first level, then the next level printed is e.getCause().getCause().

Comment: Thanks! there was a typo `getCause` instead of `getMessage`

Comment: Yes, it was my idea, even if I prefer `getLocalizedMessage()` to `getMessage()`

Comment: If this answered your question, would mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: @Tala Better would be `t != null && t.getCause() != t` i have seen many exception which reference themself

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom exception and override the getMessage() function.

here is a sample where I am collecting Stacktraces:

```
@Override
public String getMessage()
{
    for (StackTraceElement element : this.getStackTrace() ){
              result.append( element );
              result.append( NEW_LINE );
            }
            return result.toString();
}
```

You can use your own version of code to fit your requirement.